# Python code to solve classic P(n, r): Print all permutations of n objects taken r at a time without repetition

Tags: python, permutation

Python code to solve classic `P(n, r)`

Problem: Print all permutations of n objects taken r at a time without repetition.

I'm a Python learner looking for an elegant solution vs. trying to solve a coding problem at work.
Interested in seeing code to solve the classic `P(n, r)` permuation problem -- how to print all permuations of a string taken r characters at a time, without repeated characters.

Because learning is my focus, not interested in using the Python itertools "permutations" library function.  Looked at it, but couldn't understand what it was doing.  Looking for actual code to solve this problem, so I can learn the implementation.

> Example:  if input string s == 'abcdef', and r == 4, then n == 6. 
>   Output would be something like: abcd abce abcf abde abdf abef ...

There are a lot of closely similar questions, but I didn't find a duplicate.  Most specify "r". I want to leave r as an input parameter to keep the solution general.

Comment: Your example looks more like combinations. Are you looking for `abdc` as well?

Comment: You may be right, but I don't understand the question.  Please elaborate.  I might need to change the question.

Comment: The algorithm used to generate the permutations is rather abundantly commented in the source code of itertools.permutations: https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/master/Modules/itertoolsmodule.c#L2534

Comment: Means if your input is like **aa**  then output be only aa not aa, aa because you have mentioned no repetition.

Comment: I didn't think that far.  Let's assume there are no repeated characters, to keep things simple ...

Comment: @BabarBaig You list `abcd abce abcf abde abdf abef` which are all still in order wrt the original string. That is usually what combinations are, not permutations. So, since you are asking for permutations, I would have expected an example like `abdc` as well to properly distinguish perms from combs.

Comment: check this [click here](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/distinct-permutations-string-set-2/) to print all permutations without repetition.

Comment: @MayurFartade Thanks for the link, but the example it gives, is of a string WITH duplicates.  I'm willing to exclude duplicates to keep the solution simple and easier to understand.

Comment: @schwobaseggl I thought it was the other way round.  With permutations, order of characters does matter.  With combinations, it does not. https://medium.com/i-math/combinations-permutations-fa7ac680f0ac

Comment: Exactly my point. SInce you want permutations where order matters, I would have expected you to list `abcd abdc acbd acdb adbc adbc ... abce abec ...` Your sample output would be the same for combinations which are a subset of the permutations

Comment: @ThierryLathuille The Github solution uses a LOT of code to use iterators to implement a general solution.  I couldn't understand it.  Hoping someone can just give a solution for strings ...

Comment: Do check this [Click here](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/python-program-to-print-all-permutations-of-a-given-string/) string without duplicates .

Comment: @MayurFartade Thanks for the link.  I ran it in my IDE.  It has the same limitation as most readily-available solutions on the web: It doesn't seem to handle "r" as user input.  Outputs all possible combinations of length n.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This approach uses recursive generator functions which I find very readable. It is the easiest to start with combinations:

```
def combs(s, r):
    if not r:
        yield ''
    elif s:
        first, rest = s[0], s[1:]
        for comb in combs(rest, r-1):
            yield first + comb  # use first char ...
        yield from combs(rest, r)  # ... or don't

>>> list(combs('abcd', 2))
['ab', 'ac', 'ad', 'bc', 'bd', 'cd']
>>> list(combs('abcd', 3))
['abc', 'abd', 'acd', 'bcd']
```

And build permutations on top of them:

```
def perms(s, r):
    if not r:
        yield ''
    else:
        for comb in combs(s, r):
            for i, char in enumerate(comb):
                rest = comb[:i] + comb[i+1:] 
                for perm in perms(rest, r-1):
                    yield char + perm

>>> list(perms('abc', 2))
['ab', 'ba', 'ac', 'ca', 'bc', 'cb']
>>> list(perms('abcd', 2))
['ab', 'ba', 'ac', 'ca', 'ad', 'da', 'bc', 'cb', 'bd', 'db', 'cd', 'dc']
```